# Use SQLCMD to connect to Windows 2003 server

Tags: sql-server, odbc, windows-server-2003, sqlcmd

I have a series of SQL Server instances that I need to connect to from inside a docker container using SQLCMD. These target SQL Server instances frustratingly have different versions with some on Windows Server 2012 and some on Windows Server 2003. When I try to connect to the Windows Server 2012 instances and execute sql commands using a command such as `sqlcmd -S IP_Address,Port_No -U username -P password -i input_file.sql`, it works perfectly. When I try the same for the Windows Server 2003 instances, I get the following error:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

Is this just a situation where the connection syntax changes for Windows Server 2003? I have tried many different tweaks to the connection string but each returns the same message? Is SQLCMD even supported for Windows Server 2003? I would really appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the 2003 instances are running on the same port? The error seems to indicate either a wrong port or firewall blocking that port for connection.

Comment: I doubt that ODBC Driver 17 supports SQL Server 2003, if I'm honest. To answer the question *"Is SQLCMD even supported for Windows Server 2003?"* Certainly not the version you have installed, which i suspect is the one that came with SSMS 2018; that'll only support SQL Server 2008-2019. In truth, is long past time you look at upgrade paths I''m afraid. 2003 has been out of support for some time.

Comment: Yes, we verified network connectivity yesterday. I can ping and telnet the server.  I can also connect through SSMS and check the local_net_address and local_tcp_port values so I am confident that the IP and port are correct.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running on the Windows Server 2003 box?